# Dropbox oAuth doesn't redirect to redirect_url ?

Tags: laravel, oauth, dropbox

I'm using Laravel 5.1 with Socialite and SocialiteProviders/Dropbox, I have setup the app in the Dropbox console, and the routes for redirect and the callback for getting the token, the problem I'm facing is that after the user gets redirected to Dropbox to get the token, after granting the app, it doesn't redirect him to the url that I set up in the Dropbox app configuration, It just shows the token `Enter this code into MyAppName to finish the process.`
Please, I really need your help regarding this, How I can make the Dropbox redirect to my redirect_url ?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this, I forget to set the redirect_url in dropbox service in laravel.